# Execute jQuery code when AJAX postback occurs in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to execute my jQuery script when the page is loaded and when partially postback has happened.
However:

- `function pageLoad(){}`
- `$(document).ready();`

Don't do what I require. The code I want to be always executed is as follows:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].className = "";
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].className = "table table-bordered";
$(".odd").addClass("success");
$(".odd").removeClass("odd");
$(".even").addClass("warning");
$(".even").removeClass("even");
```

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: I edited it primarily to remove the unnecessary swearing. I don't know the answer myself so I tried to help you by making the question more readable. I can just as easily have downvoted or flagged it if you prefer.

Comment: You are truly helping..... sorry for my attitude....

Comment: where's the ajax code?...can't manipulate elements until they exist and they don't exist until your ajax response is available

Comment: The ajax code is generated by Yii, i cannot see it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the answer:
First, i am declaring a function on top of my page, because i want to execute it on documentload and on ajaxcallback.

Then, on the bottom of my page i set

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(fu);
```

This is what makes my function executed when te ajax callback has finished, without the need of knowing the callback's details.